# What is the syntax to open a installed android app using robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I am working on Android app UI automation using robotium. My intent is to open and close a android app 100 times.. I can record(using robotium recorder) scripts to install app and launch it.. but not able to relaunch it again. Please provide any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Hm tried this?

```
Solo.finishOpenedActivities();

// relaunch your app by calling the same Activity as in the constructor
this.launchActivity(TARGET_PACKAGE_ID, YourStartActivity.class, null);
Solo.sleep(1000);
```